# MySQL performance: DATE vs TINYINT

Tags: php, mysql

Normally my table contains a DATE column, and when it's permanently empty is 0000-00-00. Is it better to add an additional column TINYINT just to track if the row is permanently active, so my searching performance will be better? Or should I keep only the DATE column?

```
SELECT columns FROM table_name WHERE date_is != '0000-00-00'
```

versus

```
SELECT columns FROM table_name WHERE col_emplty != '1'
```

TinyInt should search faster, shouldn't it?

Comment: Could be faster but you've added a layer of redundancy. Why not do the best possible design and let your dbms take care of performance?

Answer (score 4):

If you want you can set default value for date column as null. So, you just have to check if data is `IS NOT NULL`, as adding an extra column just to see if the next column has a proper date format, doesn't make sense.

Comment: Comparing with `null` does not work with `<>`. You have to use the `IS` operator

Comment: @juergend Thanks, I forgot that.

Comment: Thanks for answers but u think that +1 column with 1 byte will hurt the table ! The 0000-00-00 will be only permanent but in search results i have to avoid that, and the design of table is very good as that. But imagine the table it will contain example more then 10K records, and i have to SELECT rows that are not NULL '0000-00-00'. If checking the date IS NOT NULL will be faster then having TINYINT in where clouse !?

Comment: whether you put an extra column or not, you still have to have a "where" condition and let assume if you have few more columns like "created_at", "last_activity" etc basically date-time related column then will you add few more column that will have tiny int as data type? I think I've made my point :D

Comment: Yes for sure there is going to be WHERE condition, but the thing is would it run faster to have DATE or TINYINT on where condition.. And yes you are right that i cant add ++ columns for every new thing i want to have in where condition.  But in my case +1 Tinyint will make the Search performance faster ,thats my question..

Comment: Try adding an extra column if that ease your work as well as check performance of your DB (with and without extra column, chances are that it would be considerably same).

Answer (score -1):

**Adding a new field** or **allowing NULL** to a column will solve your problem but both are **not** a good practice.

If 99% of time you are going to select data on the basis of date(can be default date on any date) or going to update this date field what you can do here is to create a int column instead of date type and keep the value as yyyymmdd(eg: instead of keeping '2015-04-19'(date) keep data as 20150419 (10000*year + 100*month + date) and compare the date value), as this is an int column both searching and updating table will be fast.

Comment: don't you think that you are over doing the process? especially when "date" data type already exist then why not use default process and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't think so. If you have huge amount of data and you know you have to apply where clause on date then this process will be better.